# Capybara, Ambiguous match, found 2 elements - how to select an unknown, unique selector

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, capybara

I am writing a UI test for a page that has two buttons that I can successfully target, but I cannot find the unique selector that is hidden to describe each button.  I have my test spec file that is validating response, and referencing a class method file where I am defining where the element is.

I'm first asking if there is a way to target the " Send Club Assignment " string, because it's a unique thing, but it seems out of reach since it's not a text: element, and/or not in the element I'm actually matching, but nested in the <span class=' ... yadda yadda ... /span> under it.  Or I want to know how to format either the test file, or class method file to be able to select the 2nd of the elements I am currently selecting

Here is a snippet of the test file

```
it "should log in, and add a club assignment to a test user" do
  profile_memberships_tab.load
  league_login
  expect(profile_memberships_tab.actionable_redirect_header).to be_visible
  click_on(profile_memberships_tab.send_club_assignment_button).click
  expect(page).to have_content("Send Direct Club Assignment Request")
end
```

Here is the class method file

```
class ProfileMembershipsTab < SitePrism::Page
  set_url "[webpage url]"
  element :send_club_assignment_button, "button", class: "se-button--medium" # this fails
  element :actionable_redirect_header, "h1", text: "Actionable Redirect" # this works
end
```

Here is a snippet of what the html looks like that I'm targeting
[image]

I have tried

- putting class method file to

  send_club_assignment_button, "button", class: "se-button--medium", text: "Send Club Assignment"

Which returns :

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible css "button" with text "Send Club Assignment" with classes [se-button--medium]
```

- I tried wrapping putting the class file in multiple lines so I could make it the last one

  element :send_club_assignment_buttons, "button", class: "se-button--medium"
  element :send_club_assignment_button, send_club_assignment_buttons.last
- I tried changing the test file to

click_on(profile_memberships_tab.last(send_club_assignment_button)).click

- And other variations on the above - all of those return this:

  Capybara::Ambiguous:
  Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible css "button" with classes [se-button--medium]

Comment: Try text: "SEND CLUB ASSIGNMENT"

Comment: Or you can try `element :send_club_assignment_button, :button, 'Send Club Assignment', class: 'se-button--medium'` --- The first is because the :text parameter should be matched against the document contents with CSS applied, and this option because it would use Capybaras 'button' selector which matches the locato rusing XPath against the HTML contents directly

Comment: In both cases - the response is      

Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link or button #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="button" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/SECTION[1]/CONTACTS-OVERVIEW[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/CONTACTS-LIST[1]/SECTION[1]/DIV[1]/ORG-PERSONA-MEMBERSHIPS[1]/DIV[1]/SECTION[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/SE-CARD[1]/DIV[2]/SE-CP-CARD-CONTENT[1]/SE-EMPTY-STATE[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/SE-CP-EMPTY-STATE-DESCRIPTION[1]/SE-BUTTON[2]/BUTTON[1]">

Comment: Right so both are finding the element but now `click_on` is failing because you're passing it an element when it doesn't take an element.  Instead you should just be doing  - `profile_memberships_tab.send_club_assignment_button.click`.  If you want to use `click_on` it would just be `click_on('Send Club Assignment', class: 'se-button--medium')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "find" helper from Capybara, example:

```
find('se-button--medium').click
```

With this helper, you can find elements based on css classes and then, click them

See more in: https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master#finding